# Hadoop installation issue

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-plugins

After installing hadoop on oracle virtual box using ubuntu, everything is working fine . But when I am running localhost:50070 on browser, I am getting namenode health but not Legacy UI option at right bottom corner,through which I could browse the file system. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have installed Hadoop 2.7.x, check this fix to remove Legacy UI option from Namenode UI - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6657

Also you should now have a drop down menu item named 'Utilities' under that 'Browse the filesytem'.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs.Though that utility option contains" browse file system" but with that we are not able to see the content of file.